# Facebook share not recognizing image thumbnail

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created an facebook share button using the url below:

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=http://www.elementalworks.nl/KPJH/Homepage&p[images][0]=http://www.elementalworks.nl/KPJH/images/logo.jpg&p[title]=KPJ Halsteren voor jouw schuurfeesten en trekkertrek activiteiten&p[summary]=Schuurfeesten, Trekkertrek en allerlei andere gezellige bijeenkomsten vindje bij KPJ Halsteren
```

In addition to this i placed the open graph image tag as follows:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.elementalworks.nl/KPJH/images/logo.jpg" />
```

BUT.. the facebook debugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) sais that the image is'nt big enough, it has to be 200x200. The image itself is 365x250 50kb.

Strange thing is that in the small preview window below the debugger the image does show.

So why doesnt it show at the moment of sharing? You cna find the page in question here: www.elementalworks.nl/KPJH